# How to add two assembly arrays in arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, avr, array, code-review, assembly

Hey guys what I'm trying to do is to sum two arrays and return a new array; for example if given

```
  uint8_t a[] = {2, 4, 6};
  uint8_t b[] = {1, 2, 3};
```

I should get `{ 3, 6, 9}` What I'm trying to do is have a .ino file call on an assembly file that will do this in assembly and not in C and this is what I currently have in assembly:

```
// mimics void sumArrays(uint8_t *a, uint8_t *b, uint8_t *c, byte length){} method
    .global sumArrays
    sumArrays:
      //r18 is the byte length
      //r24 and r25 first  array 31,30
      //r23 and r22 second array 29,28
      //r21 and r20 third  array 27,26

      mov r30, r24
      mov r31, r25
      mov r28, r22
      mov r29, r23
      mov r26, r20
      mov r27, r21
      ldi r17, 0 //counter variable
      ldi r19, 1
      call printRegs
      //jmp sumLoop

      ret

    sumLoop:
      cp r17, r18
      brge endSumLoop
      ldi r16, 0
      add r16, Z+
      add r16, Y+
      st X+, r16
      add r17, r23
      jmp sumLoop:
    
    endSumLoop: 
      ret
```

However, I get `sketch/assignment13.S:65: Error: constant value required` which is most likely from the

```
add r16, Z+
add r16, Y+
```

Lines but otherwise, how would I add it to a temporary variable while progressing the pointer?

Comment: Why are you using assembly for this instead of C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> add r16, Z+
> ```

You probably meant something like

```
add r16, memory[Z+]
```

However, the AVR is a RISC processor. It has instructions to address the
memory, and instructions to do arithmetics, but it has no “complex”
instructions that both address the memory *and* do arithmetics with the
addressed data. So you have to use separate instructions to:

1. Load (`ld`) the data from RAM
2. do the arithmetics
3. store (`st`) the result in RAM

Now, looking at your assemble code, I have a few comments:

1. If you are mixing assembly and C/C++, you should pay attention to the
   [ABI conventions](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/avr-gcc). Specifically, some registers, like r28 and
   r29, “belong” to the caller. If your function needs to use them, it
   should save their contents (typically by `push`ing them to the
   stack) before clobbering them, and restore them (`pop`) before
   returning.
2. For adding two 8-bit numbers (a + b), a single addition is enough.
   There is no point in starting the addition with zero (i.e. computing
   0 + a + b).
3. For managing the counter, it can be more convenient to decrement the
   initial count you where given (like in C: `if (--length) return;`)
   rather than using an extra variable that is incremented.
4. There is no need to split such a simple function into smaller
   functions.